# How to evaluate a C expression with literal suffixes U L F?

Tags: c, expression, evaluate

I need help understanding how the expression below should be interepted, because I have no clue. help please.

```
Expression: 11U/22L*(3.75F-2)+3./6+.25/1.F;
Choices:
A) 0.5       B) 0.25
C) 0.0       D) 0.75
```

Comment: What value do you get if you use the expression in code, then run that code and print the answer?

Comment: i got 0.75 .but i want to know how to get this result without running the code.

Comment: Do you see that `11U/22L` will be `0` due to integer division? So D) 0.75 by inspection: 0 + 0.5 + 0.25. The `1.F` is a `float` with value 1.

Comment: yeah. i got it, thank you.

Comment: Do you know *what* these suffixes are?

Comment: @EugeneSh. U:unsigned , L:long, F:float ... right?

Comment: Correct. In addition you should know that integers without the suffix are `int` and fractionals are `double`

Comment: @EugeneSh.thank you.

Comment: `11U/22L` means "I don't really understand integer promotion so I'll just toss in some suffixes and hope for the best".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

U: unsigned int
L: long int
F: float

integral literal: [signed] int
FP literal (without suffix f/F): double

11U / 22L * (3.75F - 2) + 3. / 6 + .25 / 1.F
-> unsigned / long * (float - int) + double / int + double / float

Now, we need an understanding of [operator precedence](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_precedence) and [type promotion (conversion)](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/conversion).

---

**Then the expression evaluates to:**

unsigned / long -> promoted to long
*
(float - int) -> promoted to float
+
double / int -> promoted to double
+
double / float -> promoted to double

---

**Put the values in:**

11U / 22L -> 0L
*
(3.75F - 2) -> 1.75F
+
3. / 6 -> 0.5
+
.25 / 1.F -> 0.25

---

=> 0L * 1.75F + 0.5 + 0.25

=> 0F + 0.5 + 0.25

=> 0.5 + 0.25

=> `(double) 0.75`